# Why all rows will changed when I only change one row in a list in python?

Tags: python

I wrote a code for searching treasures. As a code indicates, when I drop a sonar it will show the hint for chests. However, in my code, all rows will change. I really don't know why. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks so much!

```
import random,math

class OcenTreasure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board=[]
        self.chests=[]
        self.treasure=3
        self.sonar=20
        self.drop=[]

    def get_board(self):
        colume=['~']*60
        for y in range(0,15):
            self.board.append(colume)
        return self.board

    def drawBoard(self):
        row=0
        print('             1         2         3         4         5 ',\
              '   012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789',\
              sep='\n')
        while row<15:
            if row<10:
                line=''.join(self.board[row])
                print(' '+str(row),line,str(row))
            if row>=10:
                line=''.join(self.board[row])        
                print(str(row),line,str(row))
            row+=1
        print('             1         2         3         4         5 ',\
              '   012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789',\
              sep='\n')  

    def getChests(self):
        cont=True
        while cont==True:
            for i in range(0,3):
                a=random.randint(0,14)
                b=random.randint(0,59)
                aList=[b,a]
                if aList in self.chests:
                    aList=[]
                else:
                    self.chests.append(aList)
                    cont=False

        return self.chests


    def dropSonar(self,choice):
        if choice in self.drop:
            self.sonar-=1
            return (print('You already dropped a sonar there. You lost another sonar device'))
        else:
            self.drop.append(choice)
        pos=choice.split()
        x=int(pos[0])
        y=int(pos[1])
        for item in self.chests:
            xgap=math.fabs(x-item[0])
            ygap=math.fabs(y-item[1])
            if ygap>5 and xgap>9:
                self.board[y][x]='O'
            else:
                if xgap==0 and ygap==0:
                    self.board[y][x]='X'
                    self.chests.remove(item)
                    self.treasure-=1
                if xgap<2*ygap:
                    self.board[y][x]=str(int(xgap))
                if xgap>=2*ygap:
                    if ygap==1:
                        self.board[y][x]='a'
                    if ygap==2:
                        self.board[y][x]='b'
                    if ygap==3:
                        self.board[y][x]='c'
                    if ygap==4:
                        self.board[y][x]='d'                    
                    if ygap==5:
                        self.board[y][x]='e'
        self.sonar-=1

gameOver=False 
t=OcenTreasure()
t.get_board()
a=t.getChests()
print(a)
while gameOver==False:
    t.drawBoard()    
    print(t.board)
    print('Where do you want to drop your sonar?')
    if t.sonar>0:
        choice=input('Enter coordinates x y (x in [0..59] and y in [0..14]) (or Q to quit and H for help): ').lower()
        if choice=='q':
            print('The chests were in: '+str(t.chests))
            print('Thank you for playing Ocean Treasures')
            gameOver=True
        else:
            t.dropSonar(choice)
            if t.treasure==0:
                print('Well done! You found all the 3 treasure Chests using '+\
                      str(t.sonar)+' out of 20 sonar devices.')
                gameOver=True
            else:
                print('You have '+str(t.sonar)+\
                      ' sonar devices available. Treasures found: '\
                      +str(3-t.treasure)+'. Still to be found: '+\
                      str(t.treasure)+'.')
    else:
        print('You lost all your 20 sonar devises.')
        print('The remaining chests were in: '+str(t.chests))
        gameOver=True
```

Comment: Try narrow the scope of your  problem

Answer (score 1):

In python lists are mutable. Also, when you insert a list inside another list, what is stored is the reference.

Look at what happens if you run this code (I used the same variable names as in your `getChest` method)

```
aList = [1,2,3]
chests=[]
chests.append(aList)
chests.append(aList)

print chests
aList[0] = 999
print chests
```

You can search for the two terms "reference" and "mutable" in any python book for a more thorough explanation.  Also have a look a the `copy` module (look for "deep copy" and "shallow copy" concepts).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look at that!

Answer (score 1):

In your `get_board` function, you are creating `colume`, and then appending it to board over and over again - but this doesn't create a new list each time, it's the same object.

```
def get_board(self):
    colume=['~']*60
    for y in range(0,15):
        self.board.append(colume)
    return self.board
```

Each time this function does `self.board.append(colume)` it's not doing "add the contents of 'colume' to the end of 'self.board'", instead it's saying "add another reference to 'colume' to self.board", so that every entry in `self.board` is the same object. You can test this with `id` to get the internal identifier of an object. It should be different for each one.  When I tried it:

```
>>> board = list()
>>> colume=['~']*60
>>> for y in range(0,15):
...     self.board.append(colume)
>>> id(board[0])
140498301136840
>>> id(board[1])
140498301136840
>>> id(board[2])
140498301136840
```

Instead, if you do this:

```
>>> board = list()
>>> for y in range(0,15):
...     board.append(['~'] * 60)
>>> id(board[0])
140498301203376
>>> id(board[1])
140498301176432
>>> id(board[2])
140498301204456
```

All different objects, and changing one doesn't change the other 'rows' of the board.

Comment: Thank you so much! You precisely pointed out what is my mistake! Really appreciate it!